# How to integrate FileNet Virtual Viewer of ICN into web application?

Tags: filenet-p8

How can i integrate Daeja Virtual Viewer of ICN into my web application?
I want to display in iFrame of my application's page seamless viewer with specific document.
Environments:
My web application
WAS 8.5
Linux
P8 5.2.1
WAS 8.5
Linux

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using ICN's viewer itself? You can use Daeja Virtual Viewer which is a product in itself. 
http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/viewone-virtual

Comment: The specific reason is a money. We need to purchase a separate license for  Daeja Virtual Viewer.